# change slideshow automaticlally and manually with next and prev buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have this slideshow taken from w3schools that changes the image automatically every so often. But I wanted that in addition to changing the image automatically, it would also change it manually with the "prev" and "next" buttons, but the "prev" and "next" buttons don't appear anywhere in this automatic version of the slideshow. I wanted to know what I should add to make these buttons appear and work.
thanks.

```js
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides() {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

```css
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      /*max-width: 100px;*/
      width:100px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }

    /* Hide the images by default */
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
     
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -22px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

    /* Caption text */
    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }

    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }

    /* Fading animation */
    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .4}
      to {opacity: 1}
    }

    @keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .4}
      to {opacity: 1}
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
    <p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

    <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="1.jpeg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="3.jpeg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot"></span> 
      <span class="dot"></span> 
      <span class="dot"></span> 
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating buttons and learning how to trigger actions when they are clicked?

Answer (score 0):

i added this to javascript file:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
```

and this to html file:

```
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

and this to css file:

```
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

and now it changes both ways, (automatic and manual) , but when you change the image manually, the timeout for the automatic mode changes and the image change faster, and it only shows two images and doesn't show the third one, and in general do strange things.

Comment: i founded this and works fine: https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/MdJwOa